# Is it possible to export an XCFramework which itself embeds an other XCFramework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, xcframework

The last WWDC introduced XCFramework which is an easy way to distribute an universal framework.
I've been using it and it works great.

Now, let's say I have an app "A", which embeds a framework "B" (as .xcframework) which itself embeds a framework "C":

**App A -> Framework B -> Framework C**

When I do that, A can't load B, because A can't find C ("No such module 'C'").

Is there a right way to do that or any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not support the idea of cascaded frameworks. So if you add B as xcframework in your app you also need to have C as well in your App.

Comment: Hi, this is something I am trying to accomplish as well, are there any other solutions to avoid having App-A require Framework-C? Can Framework-B be something else, say a static library? Or will App-A still require Framework-C in all scenarios?